# How replace string while importing csv by link, in Google Spreadsheet, using App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

In google App Script, while trying to import via link a csv into a spreadsheet, I'd like to modify a string to correctly run Utilities.parseCsv, but the replace doesn't seem to work. Where am I wrong?
I specify that in the csv all the strings are in double quotes like:

```
name, color, age
"Mary","red","33"
"Paul","blue","34"
"John","black","35"
```

the csv I need to import is this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teamdigitale/padigitale2026-opendata/main/data/candidature_scuole_finanziate.csv

but if I try to import it throws me Exception: Could not parse text.

in the csv there are lines like this:

"istsc_tpis008004","POLO STATALE DI ISTRUZIONE SECONDARIA SUPERIORE "P.MATTARELLA"","Castellammare del Golfo","081005","TP","081","Sicilia","19",7301.0,"1.4.1 Esperienza del Cittadino - Scuole - Aprile 2022","2022-06-20T10:22:19.000+0000","2022-08-19","J21F22001670006",2.0,33.0,"A"

with double quotes next to it "" which I think creates the problem.

that's why i want to edit the csv between
var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
and
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent,',');

A thousand thanks

```
  function uploadCsv(csvUrl, sheetName, row, column) {
    var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
    csvContent.replace(/stringToModify/g, "modifiedString");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent, ',');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(row, column, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your question.  You don't need to modify any string.  Your file as is will translate to ['Mary','red','33'] which when using `setValues` will become in the cells a string,string,number Mary,red,33

Comment: What does this show `console.log(csvContent);`?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain clearly, I rewrote the text

Comment: I can't determine exactly what is wrong with your data but some lines parse as 16 values, some as 17 and some as 18.  All records have to be the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, for example, how about using Sheets API? I thought that the CSV parser of Sheets API might be stronger than `Utilities.parseCsv`. So, please test the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function uploadCsv() {

  var csvUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teamdigitale/padigitale2026-opendata/main/data/candidature_scuole_finanziate.csv";
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var row = 1;
  var column = 1;

  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const requests = { requests: [{ pasteData: { delimiter: ",", data: csvContent, coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), rowIndex: row - 1, columnIndex: column - 1 } } }] };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(requests, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, the CSV data from `csvUrl` is put from the cell "A1" of "Sheet1".
- When I tested this script, it seems that the CSV data is put into the sheet. But, I'm not sure whether that is your expected result. So, please confirm it.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)